# Why I am not getting enough location from FusedLocationProviderClient's requestLocationUpdates method

Tags: android, android-location

The LocationRequest I am using to get Location update using FusedLocationProviderClient is given below.

```
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS = 1 * 1000;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_MS / 2);
    mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}
```

I took a bike ride for 10 minutes. The distance traveled was around 5 KM. My code received just 4 locations. I am not able to find the issue with the code.

Comment: How do you know that the app remains running for your entire bike ride? Are you using a foreground service? What is the implementation of `mLocationCallback`?

Comment: @greeble31, I am using a bound service and the activity bound to the service was running during the entire duration. In the mLocationCallback, I am sending the received location to the bound activity.

Comment: I don't think your problem is going to be in the posted code. That looks fine. Can you be more precise -- was the screen awake for your entire bike ride?

Comment: @greeble31 I am not sure about that. Currently I am trying accumulate the locations inside the service itself and callback will send all the locations accumulated. I hope that will solve the problem. Thanks :)